# Django query for many to one relationship, how to retrive data many to one relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

how to retrive data many to one relationship.

```
class Ads(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)

class Aimage(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ads = models.ForeignKey(Ads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ads_image')
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

my view:

```
qs = Ads.objects.all()
```

template:

```
{% for o in qs.aimage_set.all %}
{{ o.title }} 
{{ o.image.url }} #does work
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `qs` is a *set* of `Ads`, so you can not access `qs.aiimage_set` on the *queryset* but on an `Ads` model.

Comment: how can i access the querysets of both models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qs` is a *set* of `Ads`, so you can not access `qs.aimage_set` on the *queryset* but on an `Ads` model. Furthermore you specified as value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), `related_name='ads_image'`, so this it the name of the manager to access the objects in reverse:

```
{% for ad in qs %}
    <b>{{ o.title }}</b>
    {% for o in ad.ads_image.all %}
        {{ o.image.url }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will result in an *N+1* problem. You can use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch the related `Aimage` objects in *bulk*:

```
qs = Ads.objects.prefetch_related('ads_image')
```